# jQuery/ajax/PHP image uploader size limit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, uploader

I have a simple jQuery/ajax/PHP image uploader:

**jQuery/Java Script**

```
$('#submit_image').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#post_upload').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);

$.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', 
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(php_script_response){
                alert(php_script_response);
            }
 });
});
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {

    echo $_FILES['file']['size'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'user/upload/'. $_FILES['file']['name']);
}

?>
```

**HTML form**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="post_image_form">
        <input type="file" id="post_upload" name="image" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit_image" class="button" value=" share " />
</form>
```

I can upload images without problems as long as their file size is smaller than approx. 50kb which is too small for my purpose. What can I do to get rid of this limit?

EDIT:
Since my post was downvoted because there is no reference in my code for the 50kb limit: There is no limit. I did not code anything like a file size limit but still there is one - Why?

Comment: Nothing in what you posted has any reference to 50kb, nor is there any reference to a limit or max size.

Comment: That is correct and that's why I am asking this question here - I did not code anything regarding 50kb an still there is this limit.

Comment: If you're using a form, you'll need to show that also. I doubt this is your full code.

Comment: You don't have a valid enctype in your form or the rest of your code. Most likely why it's failing like that.

Comment: Also you're using `$_FILES['file']` yet the name is `name="image"`

Comment: The `$_FILES['file']` refers to the `form_data.append('file', file_data);` not the name.

Comment: Either way, where's the enctype?

Comment: I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form and now it works! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You're welcome. That's what I meant. If you want the question closed and marked as solved, I can put in an answer. Or, you can delete the question. *Cheers* glad to have been of help.

Comment: If you're using the form to upload the file what is the purpose of the ajax request?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please add your solution so I can mark ist as correct.

Comment: @Musa the ajax request is used because it is no php file. Thought that would be a good way to pass it to my php file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a valid enctype in your form.

Uploading files requires `enctype="multipart/form-data"` be inside the form tags.

Modify your form so that it is like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="post_image_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```